# How to use a dictionary in Cython, inside a nogil function

Tags: python, c++, c, scikit-learn, cython

I want to use a dict like

```
{0: [1.], 
 1: [2.]}
```

I know it is illegal to work with normal Python object inside a Cython nogil function, so I want to use `IntFloatDict` in 
[sklearn/utils/fast_dict.pyx](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/utils/fast_dict.pyx).

After replacing the normal Python dict inside the Cython nogil function with `IntFloatDict`:

```
# distutils: language=c
cimport numpy as np
from fast_dict cimport IntFloatDict


np.import_array()


cdef IntFloatDict test_fast_dict(IntFloatDict a) nogil:
    return a


cdef IntFloatDict t 
t = IntFloatDict(np.ndarray([1]), np.ndarray([5.]))
test_fast_dict(t)
```

Then I came accross:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...


np.import_array()


cdef IntFloatDict test_fast_dict(IntFloatDict a):
    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test_c_nogil.pyx:9:5: 'IntFloatDict' is not a type identifier
```

What's the point above, how to solve it?

Comment: It doesn't solve the fundamental problem: `IntFloatDict` is ultimately a Python class (albeit implemented in Cython) so you _must_ have the GIL to use any of its methods.

Comment: @DavidW It should still be possible to access the internal c++ map whilst in cython (eg. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/adddf00433a961dc1186f91d791a11230f38840e/sklearn/cluster/_hierarchical.pyx#L204). But then you would end up with thread safety issues.

Comment: Your cimport doesn't look correct. Try: `from sklearn.utils.fast_dict cimport IntFloatDict` instead.

Comment: If you just want a fast dictionary to use inside a nogil function then just use the c++ STL map class. You can get access to it with `from libcpp.map cimport map as cpp_map` and use declarations like `cdef cpp_map[int, double] my_map`.

Comment: sklearn doesn't install pxd-files so you cannot cimport `IntFloatDict`. There is not much magic about `IntFloatDict` - it is just a wrapper around `std::map<int, double>`. So I would got with suggestion of @Dunes and use c++'s map implementation directly.